# Repeat Interval for Background Image

Tags: html, css, background-image

This is a very simple problem and so I must be doing something very silly: I cannot get a background image to be replicated properly inside a div.

I have reduced it the the following small example. I have a main div with a specific pixel size, and constrained to be a certain amount less than the current viewport. Within that, I have a second div that contains a fixed (non-scrolling) background image. I need to have the image in a separate div so that its opacity doesn't affect anything else.

This example tries to get a background image to be replicate 2x2 in the main div (i.e. width and height = 50%), but all the combinations that I try are basing this on the the viewport size and not the parent div size.

NB: you will need to run this example in full-screen mode to see what I mean. The main div is less that the viewport and I cannot get an integral 2x2 replication of the image.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Test background</title>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>

<style>
div.tp-main {
    background: #f0f0f0;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: thin;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    max-width: 99vw;
    max-height: calc(52.294vw - 23px);
    width: 1090.00px;
    height: 570.00px;
}

div.tp-bg { /* Separate div to avoid opacity affecting other stuff */
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://clipartart.com/images/tree-branch-clipart-png-4.png");
    background-size: 50.00% 50.00%;
    background-repeat: repeat;
    background-position: 0 0;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    opacity: 0.20;
}

</style>
</head>


<body>

<div class="tp-main">
<div class="tp-bg"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: because you made it fixed, so the background-size is not relative to the screen

Comment: Thanks @Temani. I went back to the spec and I think I read the description of 'Fixed' quite differently. The documentation of what it does is a bit vague, IMHO.